# sed edit of text with variables and special characters

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I'm on OS X and writing a bash script to edit text in a file which includes some known text with special characters. There will be a variable too which needs to be retained and some text entered or replaced.
Here is the input file contents:

```
user_pref("intl.charsetmenu.browser.cache", "UTF-8");  
user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "search.co.za");  
user_pref("network.cookie.prefsMigrated", true);
```

I currently have this code:

```
existingTrusts=`more ~/prefs.js | grep "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/);//g' | sed 's/"//g'`
trustSites="company.com,organisation.co.uk,$existingTrusts"
replacementValue='"user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "$trustSites");"'
sed -i 's/^user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris/$replacementValue/' ~/prefs.js > ~/newPrefs.js
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Useless use of more.  (google "uuoc").  Instead of "more file | grep ...", do "grep ... file" or " < file grep ..."

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here, unless you're asking how to write it in another way?...

Comment: Why use `sed -i` and then `> newPrefs.js`? Do you want in place editing or not?

Comment: I think the question is "Why does the following code not do what I expect?" And there are many reasons, starting with "`$trustSites` and `$replacementValue` won't expand inside single-quoted strings."

Comment: @Sorpigal sorry, i was copy and pasting from a messy test file and you are indeed right that the edit in place was misused by me

Comment: @WilliamPursell Just read the widespread uuoc sites and fully see what you mean and I'll learn from this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too many pipes to set your existingTrusts variable. Set your variables like this:

```
existingTrusts=$(awk '/network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris/ {gsub(/"|\);/, "", $2); print $2}' ~/prefs.js)
trustSites="company.com,organisation.co.uk,$existingTrusts"
replacementValue='user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "'$trustSites'");'

# and now finally your sed command
sed 's/^user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris".*$/'"$replacementValue"'/' ~/prefs.js > ~/newPrefs.js
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava you hit the nail on the head perfectly and what you've done makes sense to me. You saved me at the end of a long tiring week!

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

```
trustedSites='company.com,organisation.co.uk,'
sed -i '' -e '/network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris/s/, "\([^"]*\)/, "'"${trustedSites}"'\1/' prefs.js
```

This is imperfect because

- It uses unescaped `.` in a pattern where a literal `.` is presumed
- It presumes `, "` will appear exactly as that exactly where expected

These things could be fixed.